# How to add a nuget package in a MVC3 project template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, nuget, visual-studio-templates

I'm trying to hack a MVC 3 project template to automatically install elmah via nuget.

Since MVC 3 Tools update, MVC3 project templates contains this section :

```
<WizardData>
    <packages>
        <package id="jQuery" version="1.5.1" />
        <package id="jQuery.vsdoc" version="1.5.1" />
        <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.8.0" />
        <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.8.11" />
        <package id="EntityFramework" version="4.1.10331.0" />
        <package id="Modernizr" version="1.7" />
    </packages>
</WizardData>
```

So i've tried to add elmah package like this :

```
<WizardData>
    <packages>
        ...
        <package id="elmah" version="1.2.0.1" />
    </packages>
</WizardData>
```

I've also downloaded and added elmah.1.2.0.1.nupkg file in

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Packages

folder along with default packages (jQuery.1.5.1.nupkg, EntityFramework.4.1.10331.0.nupkg etc...)

Unfortunately, i keep having this error when i create a new MVC3 project :

[image: error]
<sub>(source: [free.fr](http://fabrice.michellonet.free.fr/elmah.png))</sub>

Does anyone knows how to solve this error?

At least is it something feasible with this version of mvc3 tools ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just blogged about how to do this: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/06/06/creating-a-custom-asp-net-mvc-project-template.aspx

This walks through creating and registering a custom project template.

Comment: Thanks Phil. devenv /installvstemplates has not been enough in my case. Anyway after a reboot everything's working fine now.